QTcpServer stop accepting new connections
I'm caught by a strange problem.
A listening QTcpServer that is working normally suddenly stops accepting new connections (qBittorrent webui stop working).
I did a little digging into Qt's source and found that the WSAAccept function on the listening socket gives me a WSAEINVAL error.


As the image shows, I'm listening on 50000 three days ago and it stopped working today.
The MSDN doc tells it may be an invalid level or calling accept on a socket that is not listening. But those make no sense as that socket was working just fine over the past three days.
This problem occurs frequently when the socket is listening for two or three days.
UPDATE: here is a MRE:
server.h
#include <QTcpServer>

namespace Http
{
class Server final : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY_MOVE(Server)
public:
    explicit Server(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    
private:
    void incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor) override;
};
}

server.cpp
#include "server.h"
#include <QTcpSocket>

using namespace Http;

Server::Server(QObject *parent)
    : QTcpServer(parent)
{}

void Server::incomingConnection(const qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    QTcpSocket *serverSocket = nullptr;
    serverSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    serverSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
    QByteArray x = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nServer: Boost.Beast/353\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 19\r\n\r\nUnknown HTTP-method";
    serverSocket->write(x);
    serverSocket->waitForBytesWritten();
    serverSocket->disconnectFromHost();
    serverSocket->waitForDisconnected();
    serverSocket->deleteLater();
}

main.cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    auto server = Http::Server(nullptr);
    server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 50001);
    return QCoreApplication::exec();
}


There is nothing here which makes it possible to reproduce or debug your problem. The explanation I have is that something in your code is fiddling with the sockets so that you end up with a socket for accept which is not the same socket as you listened on. But that's only wild speculation based on the few given information.

sorry about that. This problem is hard to reproduce.  It only happens after days. I can't imagine socket inside QTcpServer is fiddled since QTcpServer is a well-maintained lib and I can't access that socket from outside QTcpServer.

@isudfv Unfortunately, if you're not able to reproduce it consistently, we cannot really help you in any way if not by making wild guesses, which is not the purpose of SO. For what we know, it could be a problem on your code, a Qt bug, or even an issue with your network. If the problem cannot be reproduced in a deterministic way, nobody could answer you but yourself.

My guess is there is probably some Undefined Behavior somewhere in your code, and the listening socket inside the QTcpServer is probably just an unwitting victim, getting overwritten in memory or something like that after a few days.
